# Schedule a cronjob to run every 2 1/2hours

Tags: linux, cron, scheduled-tasks, schedule

I would like to run a cronjob every 150 minutes. Is it possible? Any tip would be much appreciated.

Comment: My bad. I meant every **150** minutes.

Comment: It might be simpler to schedule it to run every two hours.

Answer (score 2):

Two cron jobs:

```
00 1,6,11,16,21 * * * /command
30 3,8,13,18,23 * * * /command
```

or write a script that calls the job after 2.5 hours, and call the job and your script every 5 hours

Comment: Probably need to figure out from OP what to do with uneven distribution - there are only 1.5 hrs between `23:30` and `01:00`.

Comment: Yea. If you need uneven distribution, writing a 2 line bash script with sleep 9000 and the job is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally do this quite easily with a couple of separate `crontab` entries, one for the five-hour jobs, the other for the in-between jobs:

```
0  0,5,10,15,20 ...
30 2,7,12,17,22 ...
```

keeping in mind that the gap between the last job for a day and the first job the following day is only an hour and a half (2.5 doesn't divide evenly into 24).

If you *really* need a two-and-a-half-hour gap, you can run your job as often as you need to but only execute the *payload* of said job when needed.

One way to do this is to use a state file to maintain the last time the payload was run and then only run the payload after some suitable time has passed. For example, this script will only run the payload (the final `echo`) every seven seconds, regardless of how often the script is called:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Configuration items.

stateFile=/tmp/lastTime.txt # File holding time of last payload run.
minGap=7                    # How often payload should run (seconds).

# Get last payload run time (with checks for non-valid data).

((lastTime = 0))
[[ -f ${stateFile} ]] && lastTime="$(cat ${stateFile})"
[[ "${lastTime}" =~ [1-9][0-9]* ]] || ((lastTime = 0))

# Exit if not enough time elapsed, else update last payload run time.

thisTime=$(date +%s)
((timeGap = thisTime - lastTime))
[[ ${timeGap} -lt ${minGap} ]] && exit
echo ${thisTime} >${stateFile}

# This is the payload section, put whatever code you want here.

echo "[${lastTime}] [${thisTime}] [${timeGap}]"
```

Assuming you've called that script `runme.sh`, you can test it with:

```
while true ; do ./runme.sh ; sleep 1 ; done
```

This will run it every second but you'll notice the payload is only done every seven seconds (other than the first time), as expected:

```
[0] [1503908311] [1503908311]
[1503908311] [1503908318] [7]
[1503908318] [1503908325] [7]
[1503908325] [1503908332] [7]
[1503908332] [1503908339] [7]
[1503908339] [1503908346] [7]
[1503908346] [1503908353] [7]
```

For your particular case, you would set `minGap` to be 9000 (two and a half hours, in seconds) and have `cron` run the script based on the *maximum* amount of time you'd wish to wait after the gap has passed.

For example, let's say you're happy with a potential delay of five minutes (subsequent jobs running anywhere between 90 and 95 minutes after the preceding job). You would then set up `cron` so that the script runs every five minutes.